# nodejs perform common action for all request

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node js with express. Now i need to perform an common action for all requests ex. cookie checking

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
   //cookie checking
   //other functionality for this request 
}); 

app.get('/show',function(req, res){
   //cookie checking
   //other functionality for this request 
});
```

Here cookie checking is an common action for all request. So how can i perform this with out repeating the  cookie checking code in all app.get.

Suggestions for fixing this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [loadUser example from the express docs on Route Middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware).  The pattern is:

```
function cookieChecking(req, res, next) {
    //cookie checking
    next();
}


app.get('/*', cookieChecking);

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    //other functionality for this request 
}); 

app.get('/show',function(req, res){
   //other functionality for this request 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`app.all` or use a middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Using middleware is high reccomended, high performable and very cheap. If the common action to be performed is a tiny feature I suggest to add this very simple middleware in your **app.js** file:

```
...
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    //common action
    next();
});...
```

If you use *router* : write the code before the `app.use(app.router);` instruction.